# Using Linq to check XML files for missing or extra records

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

I have two XML files (I’ll call them A and B) that contain duplicate records but one of the files may have extra records or possibly a few less. I need to write some Linq code that will compare both files to tell me if file “A” has records that aren’t in file “B”. I also need to do the reverse and select records that are in file “B” but not in file “A”. The XML in each file looks similar to this:

```
<importJob>
  <entities>
    <entity id="7eaab021-1c05-4385-b820-50aa619c9a99" >
      <field name="RuleTypeId" value="a29b9bce-d1f5-4c11-879f-f1a572b6ff0a" />
      <field name="Name" value="Group1" />
      <field name="Notes" />
      <field name="EntityId" value="14B03381-C09C-4B69-A749-F33A4B3F0305" />
      <field name="Selector" />
    </entity>
    <entity id="69cd0eab-d10d-46fb-b1a3-018fd9d6aa97" >
      <field name="RuleTypeId" value="a29b9bce-d1f5-4c11-879f-f1a572b6ff0a" />
      <field name="Name" value="Group2" />
      <field name="Notes" />
      <field name="EntityId" value="1eaab021-1c05-4385-b820-50aa619c9a99" />
      <field name="Selector" />
    </entity>
  </entities> 
</importJob>
```

The comparison needs to be done on the entity “id” attribute. If a record exists in both files with the same id then that is a match. The “field” values of both could be different but I would still want to see this as a match.

Assuming the above XML was in file “A” and the following XML is in file “B”, I would expect an output to say record “69cd0eab-d10d-46fb-b1a3-018fd9d6aa97” is in file “A” but not in file “B”. Note that although the content of records “7eaab021-1c05-4385-b820-50aa619c9a99” are both different, the id matches so shouldn’t be flagged as not in file “B”

```
<importJob>
  <entities>
    <entity id="7eaab021-1c05-4385-b820-50aa619c9a99" >
      <field name="RuleTypeId" value="0eaab021-1c05-4385-b820-50aa619c9a99" />
      <field name="Name" value="Group9" />
      <field name="Notes" />
      <field name="EntityId" value="05e3b0d2-6f15-4c3e-b737-01ee5b1b1ae1" />
      <field name="Selector" value="1" />
    </entity>
    <entity id=" 96AA845C-2848-49E3-8BA6-F50F34F66749" >
      <field name="RuleTypeId" value="a29b9bce-d1f5-4c11-879f-f1a572b6ff0a" />
      <field name="Name" value="Group10" />
      <field name="Notes" />
      <field name="EntityId" value=" 53431D25-F7C4-4A8A-8E12-43F4D29BF46A" />
      <field name="Selector" />
    </entity>
  </entities> 
</importJob>
```

I started by using this Linq statement but it looks at the whole node. I tried adding an attribute reference but then it wouldn’t build. Anyone help me out on this?

```
var diff = fileA.Descendants("entity").Except(fileB.Descendants("entity"), new XNodeEqualityComparer());
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First - select entity ids from both files. You can cast id attribute to `Guid` when projecting query. That will return collection of guids:

```
var idsA = xdocA.Descendants("entity").Select(e => (Guid)e.Attribute("id"));
var idsB = xdocB.Descendants("entity").Select(e => (Guid)e.Attribute("id"));
```

Then use [`Enumerable.Intersect`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb460136%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [`Enumerable.Except`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb300779%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to find common ids in both sequences and ids which exist only in second sequence:

```
IEnumerable<Guid> inBothFiles = idsA.Intersect(idsB);
IEnumerable<Guid> onlyInFileB = idsB.Except(idsA);
```

Comment: Thanks for this, it'll do what I need just fine.

Answer (score 0):

assuming you have both files as an xDoc:

```
var aIds = fileA.Descendants("entity").Select(x=> x.Attribute("id").Value()).ToList();
var bIds = fileb.Descendants("entity").Select(x=> x.Attribute("id").Value()).ToList();
var noMatches = aIds.Select(x=> !bIds.Contains(x).Tolist();
noMatches.AddRange(bIds.Select(x=> !aIds.Contains(x).Tolist());
```

This will get you the list of Ids where there are not matches, modify a bit and you can get what you want (selecting out a new object that is a NV pair of the file name and id for example).